# Does casting etherealness on a target who is casting simulacrum stop the casting of simulacrum?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, simulacrum

If Wizard A is casting *simulacrum* (12 hour casting time) and Wizard B casts *etherealness* on Wizard A (at a higher level, so it can target others too), does that prevent Wizard A from completing *simulacrum*?

Wizard A is a willing target of the *etherealness* spell.

Comment: Please explain, as you did in the comment to my answer (now deleted) about the higher level spell functioning on etherealness.  That is a core detail in the situation you are talking about.   Your question is unclear by your not including that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Scenario 1: Wizard A casts *etherealness* on Wizard B who is casting *simulacrum* (does not interrupt casting)

> **Longer Casting Times**
> Certain spells (including spells cast as rituals) require more time to
> cast: minutes or even hours. When you cast a spell with a casting time
> longer than a single action or reaction, **you must spend your action
> each turn casting the spell, and you must maintain your concentration
> while you do so.** If your concentration is broken, the spell fails, but
> you don't expend a spell slot. If you want to try casting the spell
> again, you must start over. ([D&DB](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/phb/spellcasting#LongerCastingTimes))

So, having a spell on you doesn't cost you any actions so that is not a problem.

There is also no issue here with concentration. You can be under the effects of multiple spells at once even if you cast them yourself (as long as they don't require concentration).

The only conditions for breaking concentration are:

- Casting another spell that requires concentration.
- Taking damage.
- Being incapacitated or killed.

Since having *etherealness* cast on you results in none of those things, your concentration is intact.

However, a potential problem comes up when it comes to the targeting of *simulacrum*. *Simulacrum* has a range of touch, so, to complete the casting, you must have the creature you are copying at touch range for the full duration.

> You shape an illusory duplicate of one beast or humanoid that is within range for the entire casting time of the spell.

This means that whoever you are copying must travel with you into the ethereal plane. If you are duplicating yourself, then this should not be an issue.

As long as you keep targeting correctly, there is no reason why this should not work.

---

*I know you didn't ask this, but for completeness*

### Scenario 2: Wizard A casts *etherealness* on themself while casting *simulacrum* (interrupts casting)

The PHB says that you must concentrate when casting a spell with a duration longer than one action.

> **Longer Casting Times**
> Certain spells (including spells cast as rituals) require more time to
> cast: minutes or even hours. When you cast a spell with a casting time
> longer than a single action or reaction, **you must spend your action
> each turn casting the spell**, and you must maintain your concentration
> while you do so. If your concentration is broken, the spell fails, but
> you don't expend a spell slot. If you want to try casting the spell
> again, you must start over. ([D&DB](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/phb/spellcasting#LongerCastingTimes))

Thus, Wizard A must spend their action each round for 12 hours only for the casting of *simulacrum*. However, casting *etherealness* takes an action. So, taking that action to cast *etherealness* would interrupt and cancel Wizard A's casting of *simulacrum*.

Comment: Ah, but *when* do you need to touch them? At the start, the end or throughout?

Comment: @DaleM:  apparently throughout: "one beast or humanoid that is **within range for the entire casting time of the spell**". It's kind of gross now that I think about it: touching a person for 12 full hours.

Comment: Thanks for doing this answer, I was in the process of updating my answer when internet connection went down hard.

Answer (score 3):

*Etherealness* would not necessarily interrupt the casting of *Simulacrum* by itself.  Nothing about becoming ethereal involves (a) casting another spell that requires concentration, (b) taking damage, or (c) being incapacitated or killed, which are the events that can interrupt concentration and therefore casting of a long spell.

However, the casting of *Simulacrum* does require having the creature being copied within range (touch) throughout the casting, *and* requires working with the snow copy as a material component during the entire casting, so if the *Etherealness* separates Wizard A from either of those, he will be interrupted.

Comment: This is straight up RAW, without even any opinions or controversial elements.  Why the downvote?

Comment: I don't know, Phil, it seems well organized.  The down vote may be the result of a lack of supporting citations.  The SE format prefers supported answers.